# Dynamic list update ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use ng-repeat in a table and sort of forms a folder tree structure. So, when I click particular row and depending on specific value I update the value after calling the function via "onclick" (ng-click doesnt seem to be working) the list gets update in JavaScript but is not reflected on HTML. Also, the row does not even show up in HTML. 
Some part of the code is below:

```
<tr id="parents" ng-repeat="dir in cachedDirectoryInfo.filesInPath track by dir.name">
                                                <td>{{dir.name}}</td>
                                                <td>{{dir.permission}}</td>
                                                <td>{{dir.modificationTime | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}</td>
                                                <td>{{dir.ownerName}}</td>
                                                <td>{{dir.groupName}}</td>
                                            </tr>


<tr ng-repeat="child in directoryInfo.filesInPath track by child.name">
                                                <td>
                                                    <a id="mylink" datamylink="{{child.name}}" onclick="var myscope=angular.element($('#importCtrlEl')).scope(); myscope.hello(myscope.selectedPath, this)">{{child.name}}
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>{{child.permission}}</td>
                                                <td>{{child.modificationTime | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}</td>
                                                <td>{{child.ownerName}}</td>
                                                <td>{{child.groupName}}</td>
                                            </tr>
```

While in JavaScript

```
$scope.hello = function (path, event) {
            Inside promise{
                  $scope.cachedDirectoryInfo = $scope.directoryInfo;
                  $scope.directoryInfo = hdfsResp.directoryInfo;
            }
 }
```

I have read some solutions here which says to use `$scope.$apply`, which does not work for me. As it give me error "Error: $digest already in progress" and if I do`$scope.$$phase || $scope.$apply` it does not get executed. As you can see I also tried the `track by`  in ng-repeat with no results.

Is there a way to do it through jQuery?
My option would be to replace and compile the `<tr>` again.

Any advice or work around?

PS: This is all inside a jQuery Steps which might be one reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling this was the solution I could find.

```
var html = "....";
$("#parents").html($compile(html)($scope));
```

Which keeps the angular part still with scope and updates the DOM as well.